# Use strings.xml values inside .Java Activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-xml

So I'm going to make my application Multilingual and making different String.xml's for different languages.
I'm also changing my texts, such as

```
String message = "Calling " + name;
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
                toast.show();
```

to

```
String message = toastCalling + name;
```

(From strings.xml)

```
<string name="toastCalling">Calling</string>
```

I'm facing a problem, that it apparently is an INT, and either cannot be resolved, or changes the value of toastCalling (Calling) to "278172" (Random Numbers)

Is there a way to get the ACTUAL value of R.String.toastCalling (Calling)

I have tried:

```
String whatever = getResources().getString(R.string.toastCalling);
```

But I don't think that's practical.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may not think it's practical, but that's how you're supposed to do it.

Comment: you can usually just call getString(R.string.blabla); but yeah that's the way you're supposed to do it and it's not that inconvenient ;)

Comment: @TomG But, Let's say the Phone's language is Spanish. It will be checking for string-es.xml. How is "getResources().getString(R.string.toastCalling);" going to get the SPANISH Xml?

Comment: Because `getResources()` is going to automatically point to the correct resource bundle for the current Locale.

Comment: @TomG Ah, if getResources() can get that automatically, there won't be a single problem. I was just having my doubts since there will be a language change as well. Thank you for your answers/comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're within the activity's scope, you can and are supposed to call `getString(R.string.toastCalling);` to receive the string. If you're not in the activity's scope, you need getResources, as in your example. This is how it is supposed to be done.

By the way, your three lines for the toast can be shortened into one: `Toast.makeText(ctx, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I have the shortened code as well. But I keep it a bit  longer, "Easier" for the other people that work on this project as well. :).  I will be using getString();. Thank you! (Can accept in 11 minutes)